# How to correct slight mismatch of Sentinel 1 GRDH and coastline shapefile?

Tags: gdal, r, geocoding, sentinel-1

I'm currently working on Sentinel 1 GRDH data with R (raster, rgdal, sp, rgeos, maptools ...). The geocoding of Sentinel data was made by the following command:

```
gdalwarp(srcfile=paste0(root,"S1B_IW_GRDH_1SDV_20181028T051004_20181028T051029_013348_018AE8_4C2A.SAFE/measurement/s1b-iw-grd-vv-20181028t051004-20181028t051029-013348-018ae8-001.tiff"),dstfile=paste0(root,"S1B_IW_GRDH_1SDV_20181028T051004_20181028T051029_013348_018AE8_4C2A.SAFE/measurement/s1b-iw-grd-vv-20181028t051004-20181028t051029-013348-018ae8-001-lonlat.tiff"),tps=T,r="bilinear",tr=c(0.001,0.001),srcnodata=0,dstnodata=0,t_srs="EPSG:4326",overwrite=T)
```

as explained at https://asf.alaska.edu/how-to/data-recipes/geocode-sentinel-1-with-gdal/

Coastline shapefile (northern Adriatic sea) was downloaded at http://www.marineregions.org/downloads.php.

when masking Sentinel 1 raster with coastline shapefile the result is:
[image: coastline-masked (black is terrain) Northern Adriatic Sea]

There is a clear mismatch that gets worser when moving south.
Code:

```
s1_vv<-raster(paste0(root,"S1B_IW_GRDH_1SDV_20181028T051004_20181028T051029_013348_018AE8_4C2A.SAFE/measurement/s1b-iw-grd-vv-20181028t051004-20181028t051029-013348-018ae8-001-lonlat.tiff"))
poly_cst<-readOGR(paste0(root,"Adriatic_coast/iho.shp"))
s1<-mask(s1_vv,poly_cst)
```

Is there a way to make the masking work? Am I doing something wrong? I am using R version 3.3.1, rgdal 1.3.4, sp 1.3.2